# How to replace specific strings characters in rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python

I've got the `df` where I need to change some characters in `NAME` columns. I have to drop the `GIC_` part, and replace `BBEG` in the middle with an empty space. So, e.g. `GIC_GBNPBBEGIN` should turn to `GBNP IN`.

```
NAME             LANGUAGE
GIC_GBNPBBEGIN      EN
GIC_WFMBBEGAU       EN
GIC_NVGBBEGHPL      EN
GIC_BBAMPRXTPKTPT   EN
GIC_2430BBEGTT      ZH
GIC_KCMBBEGIN       EN
GIC_BBAMPRXKPR      EN
```

I've tried .replace fore replacing `BBEG` with a space, but the data does not change:

```
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].replace('BBEG',' ')
```

This is what I tried to do to get rid of `GIC_` part:

```
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.strip('GIC_')
```

Also, the rows that don't contain `BBEG` have to be dropped.

Comment: Can you try this and see if it works  `df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace('BBEG',' ')`

Comment: This actually works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can get rid of rows with name containing 'BBEG' with this command:

```
df = df[df.NAME.str.contains("BBEG")]
```

Then you can perform the string replacement in *NAME* with this one:

```
bla["NAME"] = bla["NAME"].map(lambda x: x.replace("GIC_", "").replace("BBEG", " "))
```

You will get a dataframe looking like this:

```
    NAME    LANGUAGE
0   GBNP IN EN
1   WFM AU  EN
2   NVG HPL EN
4   2430 TT ZH
5   KCM IN  EN
```